# Solution to $A=CBC^T$ given matrices A and B

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Suppose if we are looking for an invertible linear transformation C such that $A=CBC^T$ given two positive symmetric matrices (full rank) A,B, what is the most efficient way to construct the linear transformation C?

If C is restricted to the class of orthogonal matrices, then it follows that AC=CB. The solution is not unique in general. Is there an efficient procedure that quickly produce a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to use a Cholesky factorisation of $A=M M^T$ and $B=N N^T$. If you let $C= M N^{-1}$, then $C B C^T = M N^{-1} B N^{-T} M^T = A$.

(If $C$ is a solution, then so is $-C$, so the solution is not unique in general.)